# Grayscale only button background but not text

Tags: css, button, text, background, grayscale

I have several buttons with different background images.
I would like to achieve to have a grayscale filter on them by default and on hover remove the grayscale filter.

I have this already but the problem is that the text of the buttons are also grayed out which i would like to avoid.
I Couldn't figure out how to apply grayscale filter only on button backgrounds but not on text.

Now I have a main css class  for the buttons

```
.box {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
position:relative;
color: red;
cursor:pointer;
text-align: center;
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
}
.box:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: grayscale(0%);
color: blue;
}
```

and I apply the backgrounds for each button in html code

`<button onclick="buttonFunction()" button class="button box" style="background: url(background1.jpg); background-size: 100%;" >Gray button text:( </button>`

Any idea how to add grayscale filter only button backgrounds and keep the button texts colored?

Thanks

Comment: Use a pseudo element and apply filter to it only. It will leave the text unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the `filter` property to an element will affect the children of that element. You will not be able to unset / reset the filter property for the children.

If you don't want to / can't use the `pseudoelement` approach in the other answers, then you could change your HTML to create the effect you want.

Add the image as an `img` element in the button, and place the text in a span. You can then apply the `filter` to the `img`.

```css
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.box:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.text {
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box:hover .text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonFunction()" button class="button box"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200x200"><span class="text">Gray button text:(</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for:) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As Temani Afif also points out pseudo elements are your way to go although I would like to add a bit different way of positioning which I believe might be more precise and more easy to adapt to a responsive design.

The key part is making the .box have the same height and line-height which will also be the height of our :after content. Then the absolute positioning (0-0-0-0) will center it automatically.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height:300px;
}

.box:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/16777216colors.png/220px-16777216colors.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.box:hover:before {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.box:after {
  content: 'Text Text Text';
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <button type="button" class="box">Button</button>
```

Comment: In your case no need to specify the height on after element. Using top/bottom is enough. Also you are not applying your style on the button but on a container of the button. It will be confusing as we can no more click on the button which make it useless

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are absolutely right! The height I left there since older IE can act up with not-fixed height pseudo but the button-clicking would have been a very bad loss. Great catch, thanks a lot!